# Why doesn't my file upload form work?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have removed all unrelated code from the script below in an attempt to narrow down the problem but even I'm now down to 'bare-bones' it still won't work.

There is no error in the web server error log concerning this and print_r($_Files) is empty. What could possibly be stopping this from working please?

The file I'm attempting to upload is 20Kb.
The php server variable **upload_max_filesize** = 100M and **post_max_size** = 101M.

```
<?
echo 'Here is some debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {

    echo "\n\nFiles Detected";

} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form
            action  = "<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
            enctype = "multipart/form-data"
            name    = "uploadImage">

            Upload:
            <input type='file' name='image'><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<? } ?>
```

Files are not detected.

Comment: Is there a firewall at you work place?

Comment: Did you add: method="POST" to your form?

Comment: ah, yes, missing post mthod maybe, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php I got caught up on the "doesnt work at work" comment ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For uploading files you need to use "post". Since you are not specifing "method" attribute for form tag default method is "get" Try setting `method="post"` for your form.

Comment: Well done! That fixed it. Thanks. Can't accept your answer for another 6 minutes!!

Comment: but, he has to work with $_FILES. Dont understand why attribute method is required in form

Comment: Because when uploading files you need to encode data into correct format to support sending file data. That is what `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` is for. GET method does not support alternative ways for encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing method="post" from the form attributes.

Comment: The default method is get, and File uploads are only possible with post method.